# How to use an IF function in Excel formula with conditions consisting of both negative and positive numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with values in both negative and positive sign. Based on the values, I want them to assign a category. The excel sheet looks like this

I have to apply the formula on the SPI values.

[image]

I am using an IF statement.

The formula I am using is:

`=IF(C3>=2,"EW",IF(1.5<=C3<=1.99,"VW",IF(1<=C3<=1.49,"MW",IF(-0.99<=C3<=0.99,"NN",IF(-1.49<=C3<=-1,"MD",IF(-1.99<=C3<=-1.5,"SD","ED"))))))`

The problem is that every time it shows only "ED". It is as if it is skipping all the conditions and running only the last case. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but check the values:

```
IF(C3>=2,"EW",IF(C3>=1.5,"VW",IF(C3>=1,"MW",IF(C3>=-0.99,"NN",IF(C3>=-1.49,"MD",IF(C3>=-1.99,"SD","ED"))))))
```

[image]

You could also consider vlookup() like this:

[image]

Which will be easier to maintain...

Comment: @Rahul If it works, then please use the check mark and accept the answer, this helps the system for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand better what is going on using a beautifier ([for example this](http://excelformulabeautifier.com/)) so your formula:

```
=IF(
    C3 >= 2,
    "EW",
    IF(
        1.5 <= C3 <= 1.99,
        "VW",
        IF(
            1 <= C3 <= 1.49,
            "MW",
            IF(
- 0.99 <= C3 <= 0.99,
                "NN",
                IF(
- 1.49 <= C3 <=- 1,
                    "MD",
                    IF(
- 1.99 <= C3 <=- 1.5,
                        "SD",
                        "ED"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

From your example is not clear which columns and row are, could you provide also excel file ?

Comment: What happens with a value of 1.495?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many programming languages, Excel can't handle defining two delimiter at once for a variable. This won't work:

```
=IF(C3>=2,"EW",IF(1.5<=C3<=1.99,"VW", ...)
```

Since excel does not recognize `1.5<=C3<=1.99`, it considers the statement as FALSE and checks what to do in that case, which at the end of your `IF` statement is "ED".

In your case, you have to use `AND()`:

```
=IF(C3>=2,"EW",IF(AND(C3>=1.5,C3<=1.99),"VW", ...)
```

I haven't tested Solar Mike's solution, but his answers are generally pretty good. (Though the part with `IF(C3>=--1.49,...` probably needs to be rewritten to `IF(C3>=-1.49,...`) :)